# openpyxl: loss of precision reading floats from Excel?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm working on OS X and have my Excel workbook with some data, which are formatted as number (here is the [Dropbox link to data in Excel](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hxz52bjupqgv72x/db_StocksHighFreq.xlsx?dl=0))

[image: data in Excel]

Now, I'm trying to import them in Python with **openpyxl**:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

# opening the file .xlsx
file_dir = './data'
file_xlsx = file_dir + '/db_StocksHighFreq.xlsx'

# with openpyxl
wb1 = load_workbook(file_xlsx)
IBM_wb1 = wb1.sheet_by_name('IBM')

# "Time" time series
Time = wb1['IBM'].columns[0][1:]

# "Price" time series
Price = wb1['IBM'].columns[1][1:]
```

OUTPUT:

1) "Time" is correctly read as datetime.time object

```
In [23]: Time[0].value
Out[23]: datetime.time(9, 30)

In [24]: type(Time[0].value)
Out[24]: datetime.time
```

2) but the "Price" time series, read as float, seems to be truncated...

```
In [25]: Price[0].value
Out[25]: 205.85

In [26]: type(Price[0].value)
Out[26]: float

In [27]: Price[17].value
Out[27]: 206.18

In [28]: Price[17].value < 206.18
Out[28]: False
```

instead of 206.1799, which is how is also displayed in Excel (Cell B19).

Any solution? 
Thanks for your attention.

Comment: I wonder if this is a side-effect of Jupyter or IPython because on my system openpyxl is reporting the value as ```ws = wb.active;
ws['B19'].value;
206.1799```

Answer (score 0):

Gabriele,

The syntax sheet_by_name didn't work for me, so I believe it must be out of date in 2.3.1. Your code worked when I used:

```
IBM_wb1 = wb1.get_sheet_by_name('IBM')
```

You can update your openpyxl version using

```
pip install openpyxl --upgrade
```

Following through the rest of your code, I experienced no issues and was able to output 206.1799.

Comment: Formatting is only relevant to openpyxl for datetimes as this is only way to identify them.

Comment: Note taken, that makes sense now that I think about it. I'll edit that part out of my comment.